# How do I add my Twitter feed to my own list?

Tags: twitter

I have a list I created and I want to add my account a member of the listed I created. I have tried looking for an answer online but can't find one.

Comment: Very strange. You can add yourself to a list on other services like TweetDeck, but not from the Twitter site itself.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you very much! :)